# ObsevreChild Firebase when in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, background, firebase-realtime-database

i have this problem that may you guys can help me 
I need to run `observeEventType` of Firebase in background state, i mean even fore or background, this method always get new object that added to `child` 
This is my code for this method

```
-(void)connectToFireBase
{            ref = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];
        [Settings sharedInstance].isLogin = true;
        NSString *area = [[NSString alloc] init];
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"areaSelected"] == nil) {
            area = @"HN";
        } else {
            area = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"areaSelected"];
        }
        FIRDatabaseReference *HN = [[ref child:area] queryLimitedToLast:5];
        [HN observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
            NSDictionary *postDict = snapshot.value;
            if (![Settings sharedInstance].hubStarted) {
                [Settings sharedInstance].hubStarted = true;
            }
            NSLog(@"post %@",postDict);
            FSOder *oder = [[FSOder alloc] initWithDictionary:postDict];
            NSLock *arrayLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
            [arrayLock lock];
            [[Settings sharedInstance].listOders addObjectLimit:oder numberOfItem:150];
            //[[Settings sharedInstance].listOders insertObject:oder  atIndex:0];
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"hubDidReceiveOder" object:nil];
            [arrayLock unlock];
            NSLog(@"oder %@", oder);
        }];
       }
```